# .NET Core - How to make configuration options available to code in referenced libraries

Tags: c#, .net-core

We have a system that consists of several MVC apps and console apps, currently built on .NET 3.5.  We are migrating to .NET Core/.NET Standard.

The app configuration information comes from two places:
appsettings.json file, which is where the DB connection information comes from, and a
Database table (collection), which is where most of the app configuration settings are stored.

What is the best method to accomplish the following in the console app, and be reusable by the MVC app:
1) Read the appsettings.json file to get the DB connection information
2) Using the db connection, read the additional configuration information from the database
3) Make this information available to the services and repositories that are utilized by the app

Comment: read up on iconfiguration and ioptions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Here is another "basics" .. https://medium.com/@dneimke/custom-configuration-in-net-core-2-193ff6f02046

Comment: It seems here is exactly your situation described in [Custom configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-configuration-provider) section in configuration documentation.